# Como chamar um método de outra Activity na minha Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Eu tenho uma `activity A` e uma `activity B`. A activity A tem o método `metodoUm` e eu precisava utilizar este método na activity B. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Ficaria muito grato.

Estou apanhando para procurar algo na internet e não encontro nada.

Comment: Nao sei se entendi bem, mas ja tentou nomeDaActivity.seuMetodo? Nao se esqueca de deixar o metodo que voce quer usar publico, para poder ser acessado de outras classes... Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Se tem essa necessidade então o seu sistema está mal desenhado. Uma Activity não pode depender de outra. Uma das razões(há mais) é que a "outra" pode a qualquer momento ter que ser descartada pelo SO Android.

Comment: O amigo @ramaral tem razão. Mas você pode dar uma pesquisada sobre o método [**startActivityForResult()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/intents/result.html), pode ser uma alternativa. Veja [**um exemplo de uso no SOEn**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais, quero (re)lembrar que uma actividade tem um ciclo de vida limitado.

Quannto a pergunta,declare como `static` os métodos a partilhar. Depois é só chamar o método da seguinte forma: `activityB.metodoUm`.

Comment: Não me leve a mal mas esta não é uma boa solução.

Comment: Não levo. Mas pode explicar o porquê de não ser uma boa solução? Estou aqui para aprender também.

Comment: Porque o contexto pode não existir dependendo da forma que ele criou a classe dele e, provavelmente, não vai conseguir recuperar, é necessário alterar a classe e criar mecanismos que tornem possivel chamar o context estaticamente.

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como eu precisava aqui Jackowski. Obrigadão ein! Então Diego, no meu método eu passo o contexto via parâmetro quando eu chamo ele, então consegui fazer funcionar certinho. Obrigado também.